# Symfony choice what class to inject

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I use Symfony 4 and Lexik (to manage JWT) and FOSRest Bundle.

When I sent a token I use this method :

```
public function getTokenUser(JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    return new JsonResponse(['token' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
}
```

As I need to add data to my payload, I create a JWTManagerCustom class that extend from JWTManager.

If I want that getTokenUser() use my Service I need to change the function signature like that :

```
public function getTokenUser(JWTManagerCustom $JWTManager) { ... }
```

I would prefer to continue to use the interface, how can I do ?

Comment: Since JWTManager implements the JWTTokenManagerInterface, so does your subclass. So the question becomes what types will the callers of your method provide? Also, if you keep the signature with the interface you can only access properties of the concrete type by type casting, and that only works if the function is allways called with the correct type, but then there's no reason to keep the interface signature.

Comment: In your services.yaml file, alias your custom service to the interface.  That will override the default mapping.